# How do i round off time to nearest hour and minute using Oracle sql query for hcm

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Input Data is of my

```
14.499
248.589
14.997
-3.7594185
```

My query is like this which I am trying

```
‘”’ || INTEGER_PART(Accrual_Balance) || ‘:’|| 
FORMAT_NUMBER(ROUND(DECIMAL_PART(round(Accrual_Balance,2))*.01*60,2)
,’00’) 
 ||‘”’
```

Output Should be like below

```
14.30
248.35
15.00
-3.46
```

Please rectify my query which I developed.
For example, whenever there are 3 decimals such as 14.997, it should be in the file as 15:00. The 3rd decimal needs to round up.
Example 2: If it was 14:499 it should come in the file as 14:30 for half an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar solution:

```
WITH dat AS
(
  SELECT 14.499  AS Accrual_Balance FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 248.589    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 14.997     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT -3.7594185 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT CASE WHEN ROUND(ABS(60*(Accrual_Balance- TRUNC(Accrual_Balance)))) = 60 THEN TO_CHAR(CEIL(Accrual_Balance))||':00'
            ELSE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(Accrual_Balance))|| ':' || TO_CHAR(ROUND(ABS(60*(Accrual_Balance- TRUNC(Accrual_Balance)))))
       END
  FROM dat;
```

Comment: -3.7594185 not getting o/p as expected, Please relook into the qurery

Comment: Adjusted, the FLOOR on the else needs to be trunc

Comment: Thanks a lot,  need one help, this query will be inside the .rtf file template format condition. so no need of select and alias, then how will write that.

Comment: Just the CASE and use the table name that Accrual_Balance column is from instead of dat

Comment: When tried with the above comment, Output did not come.

Comment: Any other way to solve this query.

Comment: What error did you get?